# median of two sorted linked lists using binary search

Tags: linked-list, binary-search

How to find median of two sorted linked lists using binary search approach?
Suppose that L1 and L2 are lists containing n1 and n2 integers, respectively, and both lists are already sorted into numeric order. I need to find the median of n1+n2 integers in the combined lists using binary search.

Comment: Linked list is single or double ??

Comment: Check it https://sites.google.com/site/ayanunplugged/data-structure/linked-list/linked-list-question-6, it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You **can't apply** binary search approach on linked list, because in lists, unlike array, the nodes are not located at contiguous memory addresses. Without  traversing, you can't simply zoom in to any of the middle node.

It doesn't matter the lists are sorted or not, singly-linked or doubly linked.

Comment: What if we maintain a counter variable to maintain the count of no. of nodes in linked list and every time traverse till count/2 and half the value of count after each iteration.

Comment: Is this approach efficient?